# Declaring variables inside a $.each loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery each loop and I wonder if it's possible to declare some variables using it. Something like this:

```
jQuery.each(["var_name1", "var_name2", "var_name3"], function(){
  $[this] = this;
});
```

Something like a variable varbiale in php.

I know I could store everything inside an object, but it won't help me.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
jQuery.each(["var_name1", "var_name2", "var_name3"], function(key, val){
        var $[val] = val;
    });
alert(var_name1);
```

The Error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]   
var $[val] = val;
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What's not working?

Comment: Yes, you can do what you are doing in the code above (though you want the 2nd argument, not `this`). What do you need help with?

Comment: Let me give you the exact error

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.each(["var_name1", "var_name2", "var_name3"], function(i, x){
    window[x] = x; // or some object in the global/outer scope
});
```